# ¿Como ejecutar catch hasta que deje de existir alguna excepciòn?

Tags: java, try-catch

¿Como ejecutar catch hasta que deje de existir alguna excepción?

Hola, estoy estudiando excepciones y creo ya entenderlas, en este pequeño código estoy pidiendo un dato flotante y al propósito ingreso un dato de diferente tipo, la primera vez se ejecuta el catch, pero si vuelvo a ingresar un dato erróneo ya no vuelve a ejecutarlo, como logro que se ejecute hasta que deje de existir la excepción? Intente con un ciclo while pero no se como preguntar si existe algo en "e"

```
public void tamano () {

        try {
                System.out.println("Escribe mi latura, soy mini");
                tamanof = in.nextFloat();
                System.out.println("Mido " + tamanof + "cm");

        } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {

                    System.out.println(e);
                    System.out.println("Solo escribe numeros por favor");
                    in.nextLine();
                    tamanof = in.nextFloat();
                    System.out.println("Mido " + tamanof + "cm");

        }
    }
```

Comment: El flujo lo puedes controlar con una variable auxiliar de tipo boolean. `while(!isCorrect){  try {... isCorrect = true; } catch(){ } }` si la entrada es correcta, cambiar a true la variable y saldrá del while .

Comment: Eso pensé, pero como lo hago?

Comment: Añadí un ejemplo base, para que se entienda mi comentario.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciona perfectamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El flujo de repetir la acción de solicitar un dato, lo puedes manejar con una variable `booleana`, evaluada en un `while`, dicha variable solo cambiará cuando la entrada sea correcta caso contrario el proceso se repetirá.

Aclarar que no tienes acceso a la variable `e` fuera del bloque `catch`, por lo que no podrías validar o controlar el flujo con esta variable.

**Ejm**

```
float tamanof= 0;
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while(!isOk){
     try {
        System.out.println("Escribe mi latura, soy mini");
        tamanof = in.nextFloat();
        isOk= true;

    } 
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
        in.nextLine(); // Para el enter :)
        System.out.println("Solo escribe numeros por favor");
    }

}

System.out.println("Mido " + tamanof + "cm");
```